# How to embed a link in email message for file attached in email using JavaMail API?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to embed a link in email for file already attached in email message using JavaMail API.

For example, I am sending an email with some attachments. Now I want to embed link for all files which are available in email message.

Could you please help me on this?

I am using below code to attach a file in email message:

```
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachFile);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachFileName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup attachment as following code:

```
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachFile);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","file");
messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachFileName);
```

In the above code Content-ID is defined as file which can used as reference in href of anchor tag as:

```
<a href='cid:html'>link text</a>
```

Comment: Note that you can simplify this to MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); messageBodyPart.attachFile(attachFile); messageBodyPart.setContentID("<file>");  And that should be "cid:file" to reference it.  Note also that the main message body and the attachment should be in a multipart/related part.

Comment: @BillShannon: Agreed with you!! But my answer is with respect of my question.