# Embed a link in email message for file attached using JavaMail doesn't work

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I'm trying to embed a link in email for a file attached in email message using JavaMail APi like  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036058/how-to-embed-a-link-in-email-message-for-file-attached-in-email-using-javamail-a).
This is my code:

```html
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String attachment = "/path/test.pdf";
File fAtachh = new File(attachment);

String htmlText = "<a href='cid:file'>test.pdf</a>";
messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html"); 
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPartAttach = new MimeBodyPart();

try {
 messageBodyPartAttach.attachFile(fAtachh);
} catch (IOException e) {
 logger.info("Exception" + e.getMessage());
}

messageBodyPartAttach.setContentID("<file>");

multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPartAttach);

message.setContent(multipart);
```

The problem is that link doesn't work:

[ErrorLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vrTP.png)

If change the last code by:

```html
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

String attachment = "/path/test.pdf";
String htmlText = "<a href='cid:file'>test.pdf</a>";

messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPartAttach = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource
           (attachment);
messageBodyPartAttach.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
messageBodyPartAttach.setHeader("Content-ID","<file>");

multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPartAttach);

message.setContent(multipart);
```

The link Works but the file name and extension are wrong:

[WrongFileName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8if8.png)

I've tried to change the file name by method:

```html
messageBodyPartAttach.setFileName("test.pdf");
```

but if I set the file name, the link doesn´t work like in the first code.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The attachFile method sets the filename and sets the Content-Disposition to ATTACHMENT.  In a multipart/related message you probably don't want those set, although it likely depends on what mail reader you're using to display the message.

There should be no functional different between using the setContentID method and using the setHeader method with "Content-ID".

Normally multipart/related messages are used to allow the html part to reference an image part also included in the message, and displayed along with the html part.  Probably no mail readers are going to display a pdf file inline with the html.

Maybe the question to ask is, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

If you just want the pdf file to appear as an attachment with a correct filename that the user can then click on to save or view, you should use the (default) multipart/mixed instead of multipart/related.  I'm not sure there's a good way to embed the link to the attached file in the html text.  If you're able to create such a message with some other mailer, you can examine the structure of that message and replicate it using JavaMail.

Comment: I try to accomplish to link the attached document in body message without show the content of file.
I've set Content-Disposition to INLINE but it doesn't work.
Anyway I agree with you.  Not seems a good idea to attach a file in the HTML text. Most of email providers could interpret the file like dangerous for system.
Thank you very much.